# Invoking gui from another class, but appears after the code is terminated

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, class, invoke

I have a class which creates a frame with jcombobox and jtextfield init, where user inserts some data. Then I have another class in which user invokes the class with the swing. Although the swing class works properly, when I invoke it from the other class it will only appear after the program has been terminated. I need it to be open till the user inserts the data, and clicks ok so that the data entered can be used further in the code.

I invoke the swing class main with this:

```
new constraints();
        constraints.main(null);
```

and the swing class main is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    { 
                        new constraints().displayGUI();
                    }
                };
                EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
        }
```

full code:

```
    public class constraints {



        private static JTextField tField;
        private MyDocumentFilter documentFilter;
        private JLabel amountLabel;
        private static String amountString = "Select Quantity of Products (in ktones): ";
        public static String textstr = "" ;
        public static String sig="" ;
        public static String sigfinal="";

        private void displayGUI()
        {
          // final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Constraints");

            final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
           // frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                    JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            amountLabel = new JLabel(amountString);

            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            tField = new JTextField(10);

            amountLabel.setLabelFor(tField);

            String[] Strings = { "Less", "Equal", "More"};
            final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(Strings) ;
            combo.setSelectedIndex(0);

            JButton button = new JButton("Ok");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                            textstr = tField.getText();



                            sig = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();

                            if (sig=="Less") {
                                sigfinal="l";
                            }else if (sig=="Equal"){
                                sigfinal="e" ;
                            }else if (sig=="More"){
                                sigfinal="m";
                            }


                       }
                    });

            JButton button2 = new JButton("Close");
            button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    dialog.dispose();

                }
       });


            ((AbstractDocument)tField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(
                    new MyDocumentFilter());        


            contentPane.add(amountLabel);
            contentPane.add(combo);
            contentPane.add(tField);
            contentPane.add(button); 
            contentPane.add(button2); 

            // JRootPane rootPane = frame.getRootPane(); 
            JRootPane rootPane = dialog.getRootPane();
            rootPane.setDefaultButton(button);

            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            dialog.setContentPane(contentPane);
            dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);

//          frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
//          frame.pack();
//          frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
//          frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                { 
                    new constraints().displayGUI();
                }
            };
            EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
    }

    class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {   
        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fp
                , int offset, String string, AttributeSet aset)
                                    throws BadLocationException
        {
            int len = string.length();
            boolean isValidInteger = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))
                {
                    isValidInteger = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isValidInteger)
                super.insertString(fp, offset, string, aset);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fp, int offset
                        , int length, String string, AttributeSet aset)
                                            throws BadLocationException
        {
            int len = string.length();
            boolean isValidInteger = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))
                {
                    isValidInteger = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isValidInteger)
                super.replace(fp, offset, length, string, aset);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The window is showing on screen.
    at java.awt.Window.setLocationByPlatform(Unknown Source)
    at constraints.displayGUI(constraints.java:101)
    at constraints.access$1(constraints.java:29)
    at constraints$3.run(constraints.java:116)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some kind of dialog, which will stop the code execution at the point the dialog is made visible.

Take a look at [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

The basic recommendation at this point would be to change the `JFrame` to `JDialog`.  Make sure you make it modal.

**Updated based on changes to the OP**

Don't forget to make the dialog modal!

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

> A Dialog can be modal. When a modal Dialog is visible, it blocks user
>   input to all other windows in the program. JOptionPane creates
>   JDialogs that are modal. To create a non-modal Dialog, you must use
>   the JDialog class directly.

*From [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)*

While slightly more advanced, you can take a look at [How to use modality in dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

**Updated based on additional exception**

The way you open you dialog/window is problematic.  It's likely to produce a window that is 0x0 in size.  Instead of...

```
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setContentPane(contentPane);
dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

Try using...

```
dialog.setContentPane(contentPane);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

After making the last set of changes to your code, the dialog appears as expected...

[image]

You may also wish to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

**Updated...**

Change the `displayGUI` method in `constraints` from `private` to `public`...

```
public void displayGUI() {
```

Change you "runner" class to look more like...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints();
        constraints.displayGUI();
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
});
```

The problem is, `constraints` main is passing the job of building and showing the UI off to the Event Dispatching Thread (which good and correct) and returning immediately, leaving the caller code to continue running...

Knew that call chain was going to hunt me...

Comment: I dont really get how it works. I have to remove my swing components and replace them with JOptionPane?? @MadProgrammer

Comment: You can simply change your reference to the `JFrame` for a `JDialog`, making sure you make the dialog modal as you do so...

Comment: So I am using no Frame at all? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @user2598911: exactly, a modal JDialog is the way to go, 1+ to this answer. Understand that a JDialog is just like a JFrame in that it can show a complete GUI, except that it can be made modal. Your main GUI will be a JFrame, and this other window that you want the main GUI to display will be your modal JDialog.

Comment: @user2598911 `JDialog` extends `java.awt.Dialog` which extends `java.awt.Window`.  `JFrame` extends `java.awt.Frame` which extends `java.awt.Window`.  The share a common ancestor and are both considered top level containers (or Windows in this case).  The `JDialog` simply has a special use case, for stopping program execution at the point it is made visible...

Comment: Updated the code. I changed Jframe to jdialog, but it wont show contents. @MadProgrammer

Comment: No errors appear now, but still the contents arent visible. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: You are right it works when I run the gui class. But when I invoke it from the other class, it still wont show but after the program is terminated @MadProgrammer

Comment: @user2598911: as an aside, don't check for String equality using `==`, since this checks if one object is *the exact same object* as another, something that you really don't care about. Instead use either the `string1.equals(string2)` or `string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)` method.

Comment: Thanks very much @MadProgrammer I would never find that without your help

Comment: @user2598911 Sorry about the runabout, but we needed to go through it to get to the end :P